NullReferenceException in Microsoft.Ml.AutoML
I'll try to be as concise as possible. This is a student project, an application in ASP.NET that monitors data and forecasts it. I then tried to integrate Microsoft ML AutoML with no progress. I can't figure out from the documentation what's wrong, and Chat-GPT can't help.
I'll remove unnecessary parts. Here's the model code where records are converted:
public class FRToDataView
    {
        [ColumnName("Label")]
        public float Label { get; set; }
        [ColumnName("DateTime")]
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

Machine learning code
public void BuildModel(IEnumerable<FloatRecord> trainingData)
        {
            var dataView = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(trainingData.Select(x => new FRToDataView(x)));
            var experimentSettings = new RegressionExperimentSettings
            {
                MaxExperimentTimeInSeconds = 60,
                OptimizingMetric = RegressionMetric.RSquared,
            };

            // Initialize the AutoML experiment
            var experiment = context.Auto().CreateRegressionExperiment(experimentSettings);

            // Train the AutoML model
            var result = experiment.Execute(dataView);

            // Get the best model
            var bestRun = result.BestRun;
            _model = bestRun.Model;
        }

Error code
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Call stack
SweepablePipeline.ctor(Dictionary`2 estimators, Entity schema, String currentSchema)
    SweepablePipeline.AppendEntity(Boolean allowSkip, Entity entity)
    RegressionExperiment.CreateRegressionPipeline(IDataView trainData, ColumnInformation columnInformation, IEstimator`1 preFeaturizer)
    RegressionExperiment.Execute(IDataView trainData, ColumnInformation columnInformation, IEstimator`1 preFeaturizer, IProgress`1 progressHandler)
    RegressionExperiment.Execute(IDataView trainData, String labelColumnName, String samplingKeyColumn, IEstimator`1 preFeaturizer, IProgress`1 progressHandler)
    AutoMLModel.BuildModel(IEnumerable`1 trainingData)`

I add machine learning in a hurry and in a hurry I can poorly understand the nuances of working with the library, I'm sorry if I made some stupid mistake
